# My Powershell loop wont stop iterating the last row of data

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Hello I have a Powershell script that used to function properly with my excel spreadsheets, but now has seemed to malfunction, and I cant troubleshoot the answer.

condensed version of the code is this

```
$pastecounter= 2
$intRowCount = $WS1.usedRange.Rows.Count       
for($i=6; $i -le $intRowCount; $i++)
{
    $startRow = $i

    <A lot of work being done to each row>

    $WS1.Range("A"+$startRow+":H"+$startRow).Copy()
    $WS2.Range("A"+$pastecounter+":H"+$pastecounter).Pastespecial()
    $pastecounter++ 
    $i=$j-1
}
```

This iterates my rows, Does the work and pastes line by line into the new worksheet, and used to work.

I started running this today and once it gets to the last row of my data it starts pasting the last row infinitely.

I've echoed all the variables which are outputting correctly until the last row, and i've tried adding a Break, but inside the for loop it breaks after pasting one row, and outside the for loop it doesn't solve the issue.

Now the only thing I can think is it might be an issue with the excel Spreadsheet. but i've deleted any empty rows, and I've cleared formatting in the excel with no help.

any Excel OR Powershell experts here that might know some troubleshooting?

Thanks!

Comment: step thru your code in the ISE or VSCode debugger.  possibly don't change $i inside your loop. `$i=$j-1`

Comment: Why are you pasting line by line? Read the data into PowerShell, do your manipulation, then `[object[]]$Data | ConvertTo-Csv -Del "\`t" | Clip` and paste into the first cell of your destination. But yeah, modifying `$i` within your `For` loop is likely the issue with your existing code.

Comment: @KoryGill thank you, this comment got me on the right direction. the code had been changed in a way that removed the copy paste function out of the J loop so $i was no longer = $j-1 but instead equal to $endrow.
Thank you for the point in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the issue appears to be with how you're incrementing the loop. I have so many questions about why you're handling things like you are, but this should help point you in the right direction...To troubleshoot, run this:

```
$pastecounter= 2
$intRowCount = $WS1.usedRange.Rows.Count       
for($i=6; $i -le $intRowCount; $i++)
{
    # // added
    Write-Host "Is `$i lessOrEqual to `$inRowCount?" -f Yellow -NoNewline
    if($i -le $intRowCount){
        Write-Host " Yes" -f Green
    } else {
        Write-Host " No"  -f Red
    }
    Write-Host ("`$i = {0}" -f $i) -f Cyan
    Write-Host ("`$intRowCount = {0}" -f $intRowCount) -f Cyan
    # // added

    $startRow = $i

    <A lot of work being done to each row>

    $WS1.Range("A"+$startRow+":H"+$startRow).Copy()
    $WS2.Range("A"+$pastecounter+":H"+$pastecounter).Pastespecial()
    $pastecounter++ 
    $i=$j-1
}
```